# Read data from emulated card content (Felica) using Card Reader - ACR1252U

Tags: java, acr1252

I am using 
`byte[] command = {(byte)0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x03, 0x03, 0x00 , 0x00}` command to make ACR1252U emulate a Felica NFC Tag, according to the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG5JnLw8zTAhXFDcAKHQrdCoQQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.acs.com.hk%2Fdownload-manual%2F6402%2FAPI-ACR1252U-1.09.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEju2tFkgnUslK03fyoWA3KEbGzQA&sig2=k7fYU7SI4lfqXr5R_lYJlw) page 71 some default data is written to the emulated tag.

I try to read this default data using `byte[] aid1 = {(byte)0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x04, 0x00, 0x03 , 0x00 , 0x12};` command and I get a respose `[B@27bc2616` which I print using `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(response)` to give `E1000000121001010009000000000001000000001C0000` which matches the expected output as per the documentation.

I only have one issue, how do I get the data  from this response `E1000000121001010009000000000001000000001C0000` and print it in a user friendly manner in java?

Comment: Define "user friendly".

Comment: @JBNizet Lets assume that the default message written to the emulated tag is "Hello World". I want to get this (default message) back("Hello World") by processing the E1000000121001010009000000000001000000001C0000 response. I hope this is clearer

Comment: OK. What bytes does your device sends when it sends "Hello World". Is it the string in ASCII? In UTF8? Something else? You need to know what these bytes represent in order to be able to transform them to a meaningful string.

Comment: I do not really know, the documentation just states that by making ACR125U emulate a felica tag, there is some default data written to it which the doc represents as A={10h 01h 01h 00h, 09h , 00h ,00h, 00h, 00h,00h,01h,00h,00h,00h,00h,1ch}. Looking keenly at this response E1000000121001010009000000000001000000001C0000 you will notice that A is its subset.